# IMFByteStream is not writeable

Tags: c#, c++, ms-media-foundation

I am starting with any System.IO.Stream like a FileStream. The FileStream is write- and readable.
I am using a basic implementation of IStream to transform the System.IO.Stream to a IStream.
For the exact code, take a look at this: http://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CSCore/Win32/ComStream.cs

The IStream implementation should support writing. Now I want to transform the IStream to a IMFByteStream to use it in combination with the mediafoundation.

I am using the [MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create the IMFByteStream.
All that works quite fine except one essential thing:
If I call [IMFByteStream::GetCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms698962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I can see that the IMFByteStream does only support reading and seeking. But I want to use it for encoding and so I need writing.

**So how can I get a writeable IMFByteStream?**

There is another strange thing: The MP3 encoder does not care about, that the IMFByteStream is not writeable and the encoding works fine (it actually writes the data to the IMFByteStream which writes it to the IStream which writes it to the FileStream, BUT it tells me that it is NOT writeable).

Comment: Too many shortcuts, it doesn't implement IStream::Stat() correctly.

Comment: Ok. You were right. Never thought about that. Had to set the type, cbSize and grfMode of the stat. Please write your comment as an answer so I can choose it as correct answer @HansPassant